# Strange Pointers Behaviour in C

Tags: c, pointers

I was experimenting with pointers. Look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int numba = 1;

int *otherintptr = &numba;

printf("%d\n", otherintptr); 
printf("%d\n", *otherintptr);

*otherintptr++;

printf("%d\n", otherintptr);
printf("%d\n", *otherintptr);

return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
2358852 
1
2358856 
2358856
```

Now, I am well aware that `(*otherintptr)++` would have incremented my int, but my question is not this.

After the increment, the memory location is correctly increased by 4 bytes, which is the size of an integer.

I'd like to know why the last printf instruction prints the memory location, while I am clearly asking to print the **content** of memory locations labelled *2358856* (I was expecting some dirty random content).
Note that the second `printf` statement prints the content of memory cell *2358852*, (the integer `1`) as expected.

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Please use `%p` to print pointers, not `%d`.

Comment: `gcc version 4.7.0 20111220 (experimental) (GCC)`. Yes, I should have used `%p`, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens with these two lines

```
int numba = 1;
int *otherintptr = &numba;
```

due to the fact the C compiler will generate a sequential memory layout, `otherintptr` will initially point to the memory address corresponding to the `numba` variable. And this is relative to the stack frame allocated when `main` was called.

Now, the next position on the stack (actually the previous if we consider that the stack grows down on x86 based architectures) is occupied by the `otherintptr` variable. Incrementing `otherintptr` will make it point to itself, thus you see the same value.

To exemplify, let's assume that the stack for `main` begins at the 0x20 offset in memory:

```
0x20: 0x1      #numba variable
0x24: 0x20     #otherintptr variable pointing to numa
```

After executing the `otherintptr++` instruction, the memory layout will look like this:

```
0x20: 0x1      #numba variable
0x24: 0x24     #otherintptr variable now pointing to itself
```

This is why the second `printf`'s have the same output.

Answer (score 4):

When you did `otherintptr++`, you accidentally made `otherintptr` to point to `otherintptr`, i.e. *to itself*. `otherintptr` just happened to be stored in memory immediately after your `numba`.

In any case, you got lucky on several occasions here. It is illegal to use an `int *` pointer to access something that is not an `int` and not compatible with `int`. It is illegal to use `%d` to print pointer values.

Comment: Understood... I also grasp the `%d` issue. But why you say *several* occasions? Is there some other noticeable issue?

Comment: @MadHatter: A is said above, firstly, it is illegal to do `*otherintptr` when `otherintptr` points to something incompatible with `int`. Secondly, it is illegal to use `%d` with pointers.

Comment: You are referring my `*otherintptr++` just with `otherintptr++`. Is that done on purpose?

Comment: I accepted the answer below just because is more suitable for a dumb newbie like me. Also, you certainly don't need any boost in reputation...

Answer (score -2):

I suppose you wanted to increment the integer `otherpointer` points to (`numba`). However, you incremented actually the pointer, as `++` binds stronger than `*`
[see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

So `otherpointer` pointed past the variable. And as there is no valid variable, dereferencing the pointer is *undefined behaviour*. Thus, anything can happen and you just were lucky the program did not crash. It just happend by chance `otherpointer` itself resided at that address.

Comment: No, I actually was investigating the very meaning of incrementing the pointer (and not the value pointed). Your answer is welcome, however!

Comment: So that was intentional? Ok then. I am just very sensitive, as this is one of the typical faults of beginners (and even professionals") in C. You should be aware, however, that this may lead to fatal failure on systems without memory protection (or if run in privileged mode).